# `make_unique_for_overwrite` still initializes `std::pair` elements

Tags: c++, memory, c++20

I was hoping that

```
auto myPairs = make_unique_for_overwrite<pair<uint64_t, void*>[]>(arraySize);
```

would give me uninitialized memory for my `pair`s. I am overwriting those later anyway and the (unnecessary) initialization is currently responsible for 120ms out of 600ms overall runtime for my algorithm.

What is the most idiomatic way to avoid this initialization?

Comment: Personally I would just use a `std::vector` and then `reserve` the memory needed.  Then when you are ready to actually create the objects in the vector, you just pay the constructor cost.

Comment: you mean doing a `reserve` upfront and then do `push_back` as I create new elements?
Unfortunately, that doesn't work for me, as my algorithm is multi-threaded and I have multiple write-fronts in that array

Comment: @Vogelsgesang "*I have multiple write-fronts in that array*" - you keep saying that. What does that even mean?

Comment: That means, I am having multiple threads which collaborate to fill that array with values. The first thread starts writing elements at offset 0, the 2nd thread at offset 20.000, the 3rd thread at offset 40.000, and so on.
In the end, they all synchronize before I hand this array over to a parallelized sort and some further processing steps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair), the default constructor of `std::pair` always value-initializes (aka zeroes) its elements.

The solution is to get rid of `pair`. You can replace it with a structure with two members.

> I know I could still just allocate ... and then `reinterpret_cast`

Attempt to `reinterpret_cast` such structure to `std::pair` would cause undefined behavior.

Comment: seems I oversimplified my question. Sorry for that, updated the question.

Actually, I have a `pair<uint64_t, void*>`. I know I could still just allocate twice as many `uint64_t`s and then `reinterpret_cast` every 2nd argument. But that doesn't feel quite right...

Answer (score 3):

> I was hoping that [`make_unique_for_overwrite`] would give me uninitialized memory for my pairs.

It does not.  The overload you are calling will allocate memory for an array of `std::pair`s, and then [default-initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) each element, per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique:

> 5. Same as (2), except that **the array is default-initialized**. This overload participates in overload resolution only if T is an array of unknown bound. The function is equivalent to:
>
> `unique_ptr<T>(new std::remove_extent_t<T>[size])`

So, this call:

```cpp
auto myPairs = make_unique_for_overwrite<pair<uint64_t, void*>>[]>(arraySize);
```

Is effectively:

```cpp
auto myPairs = unique_ptr<pair<uint64_t, void*>[]>(new pair<uint64_t, void*>[arraySize]);
```

`std::pair`'s default constructor [value-initializes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) its members, per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair:

> 1. Default constructor. **Value-initializes both elements of the pair**, `first` and `second`.
>
> - This constructor participates in overload resolution if and only if `std::is_default_constructible_v<first_type>` and `std::is_default_constructible_v<second_type>` are both `true`.
> - This constructor is `explicit` if and only if either `first_type` or `second_type` is not implicitly default-constructible.

Thus, you are effectively creating an array of pairs that are each initialized to `{0, nullptr}` before you even have a change to see the memory.

> What is the most idiomatic way to avoid this initialization?

Allocate the raw memory yourself, and then [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) the `std::pair` elements in it as needed.

Or use `std::vector` and let it handle this for you, via its `reserve()` method.

Comment: If I allocate that memory myself and then put it into a `unique_ptr<pair<uint64_t, void*>>`, do I have to ensure that I call placement-new for *all* elements?

Afaik, the destructor the `unique_ptr` would call the `pair` destructor. Would that also work if I never called placement new? Or would it be UB?

(In the presence of exceptions, I am not sure I can guarantee to always placement-new each element)

Comment: "*do I have to ensure that I call placement-new for all elements?*" - if you use the default deleter, yes, because it is going to try to destroy every element. Yes, it is UB to call a destructor on something that is not constructed. Otherwise, provide a custom deleter that destroys only the elements you actually use. Oh wait, now you've just replicated what `std::vector` does

Comment: Unfortunately, `std::vector` doesn't work for me, as my algorithm is multi-threaded and I need multiple write-fronts in that array. Afaik, that's not possible with a `std::vector`

Comment: Pretty much anything you can do with a fixed-sized array, you can do with a `vector`.  A vector is just a wrapper for a dynamic array.

Comment: I cannot:
1) just `reserve` my memory and then access the `vector` at indices past the current `size`, even if within the `capacity`.
2) use a `resize` while avoiding the unnecessary initialization. `resize` does value initialization.

As such, I don't see how `std::vector` would allow me to avoid unnecessary initialization while at the same time allowing me to have multiple write-fronts in parallel

Comment: 1) technically, you can, since `vector::operator[]` doesn't do bounds checking. Elements past the `size` won't be initialized, but memory will be reserved for them. 2) You could create a `vector` of bytes instead, and then `placement-new` each element in the array as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau 1) operator[] beyond size()-1 is UB. And it won't call destructors for those objects. 2) resize() is required and it will value-initialize (unwanted) new objects

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic 1) technically UB, yes, but would "work" nonetheless in just about every practical implementation. 2) sure, if you continue using a `vector` of objects. But I suggested using a `vector` of bytes instead, which would not create any objects at all, so you can then create them yourself within the bytes as needed. That is what `placement-new` exists for.

Comment: @RemyLebeau without resize it won call destructors. With resize it would **value** initialize empty space, not **default** initialize. Value initialization for bytes is zero initialization.

Answer (score -2):

Just do

```
pair<uint64_t, void*>* myPairs = (pair<uint64_t, void*>*)malloc(sizeof(pair<uint64_t, void*>)*arraySize);
```

Comment: `malloc` does not create objects, it only acquires memory, so any use of that pointer besides using placement new on it to actually create objects is going to be UB.

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to use `malloc()` in C++. That defeats C++'s capabilities to automate memory/object management for you. But, if you insist on using `malloc()` then consider wrapping the raw pointer inside a `std::unique_ptr` that has a custom `Deleter` to call `free()` on the memory.

Comment: @NathanOliver We're living in the future, `malloc` can create objects in C++20. Can't say off the top of my head if `std::pair` is eligible though.

Comment: OP is asking for "uninitialized memory for my pairs", this is how you get uninitialized memory.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `malloc()` implicitly creating objects only works for trivial types whose constructors and destructors run no code. That does not apply to `std::pair`, which has a non-trivial default constructor that value-initializes its members.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it has to be an implicit lifetime type, which for class types requires *A class S is an implicit-lifetime class if it is an aggregate or has at least one trivial eligible constructor and a trivial, non-deleted destructor.*

Comment: @NathanOliver I think `pair` satisfies those? The copy ctor is trivial in this case, and so is the destructor.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The default constructor is not, though

Comment: @RemyLebeau *"**at least one** trivial eligible constructor"*, not all of them.

Comment: Sounds like we've generated a new Q.  Does *at least one trivial eligible constructor* apply to copy constructors?  Personally I think it shouldn't and the language needs to be updated.

Comment: @NathanOliver Looks like it would apply. And I for one am glad that it does. :P (Found [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/special#def:special_member_function,eligible), but not 100% sure it's the same "eligibility".)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm pretty sure *eligible* is the key thing to look at here.  `malloc()` would not be able to call a copy constructor, as it has nothing to copy from, so that should not be eligble for purposes of implicit lifetime. A default constructor would be potentially eligible, but `std::pair`'s default constructor is not trivial.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's not the right trait. `std::is_trivially_copy_constructible` [says](https://godbolt.org/z/snoME44Wa) it's trivial.

Comment: @RemyLebeau [This](http://eel.is/c++draft/special#def:special_member_function,eligible) defines eligibility for special member functions, it might apply here.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Woops.  Not sure how I missed that.